# Is there a guide I can follow to convert my procedural actionscript 3 to OOP?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm wanting to change my movie clips to actionscript classes in AS3. Is there a standard list of things I need to do to make sure the classes work?

Answer (score 1):

Check out these resources:

Grant Skinners Introductory AS3 Workshop slidedeck http://gskinner.com/talks/as3workshop/

Lee Brimelow : 6 Reasons to learn ActionScript 3 http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/six_reasons_as3.html

Colin Moock : Essential ActionScript 3 (considered the "bible" for ActionScript developers): [http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0/dp/0596526946](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946)

mike chambers

mesh@adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget this excellent devnet article meant for transitioning from AS2 to AS3:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript_tips.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanna check out [Refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring) as well.